# AngularJS css performance on table column background color

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a table that I generate from JSON Data with ng-repeat.
When a user click on a link I want to highlight the corresponding column in the table with a background color. (when key.Key === anchor.output in the code)

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col ng-repeat="key in preview.data[0] track by $index" ng-class="{ 'selected-class-name': key.Key === anchor.output }">
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td id="anchorOutput_{{key.Key}}" ng-repeat="key in preview.data[0] track by $index"> {{ key.Key }} </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="data in preview.data">
        <td ng-repeat="key in data"> {{ key.Value }} </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This code is working well but I have huge performance issues on big tables,
the IE UI profiler tells me there is a lot of calls to removeChild() and appendChild()

UI profiler screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4PWp.jpg

**Questions :**

- What can I do to improve the performance of my css style update ?
- I do twice the same ng-repeat (for `<col>` and `<td>`), I'd like to get rid of it using ng-repeat-start but didn't managed to achieve it ?